# How do I make KML overlays appear in OpenLayers at all zoom levels?

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I need to overlay KML polygons on basic map in OpenLayers. I need that KML is visible on every zoom level. I did some coding, but my KML is not showing up. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OpenLayers Tutorial - Basic Map Setup</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, baseLayer;
        function init(){
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');     

            baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers:"basic"});
            map.addLayer(baseLayer);

            kml1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "kmls/MobileCoverage.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
                })
            })
        });
        map.addLayer(kml1);

       map.zoomToMaxExtent();            
        }
    </script>

    <style>
    @media screen
    {
        #map{width: 800px; height:500px; border: 2px solid black;}
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <h3>OpenLayers Testing</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My mistake, I got mixed up comparing the open and close parens.

Comment: Just a thought after looking at the .jpg of the data you posted.  Have you made sure that your data is clean.  There look to be some pretty complex polygons there, and I see a couple places where there could be crossovers within the polygon geometry.  I'm not sure how well that sort of thing is handled by OpenLayers, but it might be something to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and KML and it worked fine for me. Are you seeing the push pin? If you're not seeing anything at all, I would verify the location/spelling of your KML file.

At `map.zoomToMaxExtent();` you can't see it because the push pin is blocking it:

[image]

But zoom in and you should see it:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Tell me, where did you put my KML file? I'm using it from the folder "kmls" where is my index.html. I don't see any pin or polygon.

Comment: That's the same thing I did, placed it in "kmls" folder in root. You know... there was one more thing I did (not sure if this did anything) but I opened your KML in <oXygen/> XML Editor and it complained about a very long line and did linewrap or something (not sure) but I will paste the KML in my response incase you want to try that KML.

Comment: Okay, I'm having trouble finding somewhere to place the very large KML file (1.3GB). However when I placed my example on a public web hosting, IT DOES NOT WORK. It only works when I point to the local file in firefox to this address file:///D:/temp/jsdev/kml_test.html 
So i don't think it's the KML anymore. Maybe it's something else which I don't know, but try locally how it works for me.

Comment: It is 1.25 MB, not GB :) You don't have dropbox or google drive?

Comment: ohh right MB... here's the link but I'm pretty sure it isn't the [KML](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0hEcZdV8bW7VENuMGp5dWpEN1E/edit?pli=1#) now. Even though kmlvalidator complains about it... validators are nitpickers.

Comment: I used that KML you uploaded now and it is still the same. I really don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're using this coding I wrote up? Nothing is different?

Comment: Yeah, nothing different except I'm pointing firefox to the file:///D:/... instead of on a website `http://www`

Comment: FYI: Your KML also works on [this](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/vector-formats.html) page. Choose Format=KML and paste the ENTIRE kml into the box.

Comment: Yes.. but I can't make it work with my coding...

Comment: I can't believe it! In Chrome it didn't work, and now I opened in Firefox and everything's working, I can see my KML!! Really can't believe it. Somebody knows why I can't see my KML in Chrome?

Comment: I suppose you can open this up as a new question...I wish I knew. Maybe the number of vertices in the polygon or something like that.

Answer (score 3):

The Example here
 http://harrywood.co.uk/maps/examples/openlayers/kml.html

```
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapdiv");
map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());

var kmllayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "./mapperz-kml-example.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true, 
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 2
            })
        })
    });
```

has points lines and polygons as KML you can view the code to inspect what you are trying to do. The KML should be on a public webserver or generated from a database.

Comment: Thanks. So KML can't be in the same folder with index.html and OpenLayers.js, it needs to be on a webserver or in a database?

Comment: locally (localhost it can be) but kml in this case seems to work better from another source/location (openlayers bug?)

Comment: Is it ok to upload it to Dropbox and get a link to KML? I tried that, but KML it's not showing neither.

Comment: Does your KML have anything other than plain polygons? no network/overlays included as they are not supported.

Comment: It looks like this. What do you think? http://i50.tinypic.com/1gcc7.jpg

Comment: is the kml available online?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded it to Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6pj01rlnwaa7ol/AirCallMobileCoverage.kml

Comment: Did you see my KML? Is it ok or not? @Mapperz

Comment: dropbox is blocked, will out of work

Answer (score 2):

I think validating is essential to get past the 'is it the kml point'  I recently had some attribute issue where a CDATA block had to be used to make it validate.  I use the same KML on either openlayers maps and in google earth.  I noticed that google earth is rather picky, less forgiving than using openlayers kml support.

Hence I make sure that the kml (dynamically generated) is compliant by testing it in google earth, if it opens there, it should be ok.  I also use  [google's validator](http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.be/2007/06/validate-your-kml-online-or-offline.html%22Google%27s%20validator%22) to make sure I don't waste time on any format issues.  It wouldn't surprise me to see that Chrome xml parsing pickyness is the cause.  I use FireBug to verify what the browser did, it's available under chrome, although less functional than in firefox.

Answer (score -1):

i'm very interested in the example above.
i try to replicate in my local pc (simulated server) but it doesnt work well.
I is possible to send or post all the files involve in the example.
Best regrads
RD

Answer (score -2):

The clearest first problem is that your Javascript is wrong: the function `init()` will run when the page is loaded, while the line `map.addLayer(kml1)` will run as soon as the script is parsed. So move the `map.addLayer(kml1)` line into the `init` function to get back on the right track.

Comment: Hm, but it is inside init() function. Can you explain more detailed? Thanks.